# Some code only works when USB serial port connected

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

I'm using Arduino Uno as my microcontroller, but I got a strange behavior. I need to run several function at the same time. One to get GPS and temperature value then send every value to user's phone number when a request received by SIM800L GSM module, and another to display those value on I2C LCD. Everything works fine when my USB port connected to my computer. But when I tried to unplug the USB and using external power source from Li-Po battery I can't get a response from SIM800L module whenever I send a request message.

When I tried to create a separate program (just received a request message and then sent a response by SIM800L) it works fine even though using external power supply (Li-Po battery) without USB port plugged in. Another strange behavior is when I was using both of Li-Po battery and USB port connected then unplugged the USB port it works fine again. But when I unplugged my battery and then plugged it again without USB port connected, SIM800L couldn't send a response. What is wrong ?

This is my full code:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "DHT.h"

//sms 
char ReceivedSms;
short DHT_OK=-1, GPS_OK=-1;
String DataSms;
int _timeout;
String _buffer;
String number = "+62811XXXXXX";

//dht
#define DHTPIN 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);
SoftwareSerial sim800l(2,3);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);


// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sim800l.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.backlight();
  _buffer.reserve(50);
  ReceiveMode();
}

void loop()
{
   displayInfo();
 
}

void displayInfo()
{
  String RSMS;

  while(sim800l.available() > 0) {
      ReceivedSms = sim800l.read();
      RSMS.concat(ReceivedSms);
      GPS_OK = RSMS.indexOf("All");
   }
   
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Latitude  : ");
    lcd.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Longitude : ");
    lcd.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Suhu       : ");
    lcd.println(dht.readTemperature());
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Kelembaban : ");
    lcd.println(dht.readHumidity());
    delay(2000);
   
    if(GPS_OK!=-1)
        {
        String link = "http://www.google.com/maps/place/" + String(gps.location.lat(),6) + "," + String(gps.location.lng(),6);
        DataSms = "ALL\nSuhu = "+String(dht.readTemperature(),1)+" C"+" \nKelembaban ="+String(dht.readHumidity(),1)+" %"+" \nMaps = "+link;
        SendMessage();
        ReceiveMode();
        GPS_OK = -1;
        }
  }
  else
  {
 
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("GPS not found");
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Suhu      :");
    lcd.println(dht.readTemperature());
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Kelembaban:");
    lcd.println(dht.readHumidity());
    delay(2000);
   
    if(GPS_OK!=-1)
       {
        DataSms = "ALL\nSuhu = "+String(dht.readTemperature(),1)+" C"+" \nKelembaban ="+String(dht.readHumidity(),1)+" %"+" \nMaps = Lokasi Tidak Ditemukan";
        SendMessage();       
        ReceiveMode();
        GPS_OK = -1;
       }
  }

}

String _readSerial() {
  _timeout = 0;
  while  (!sim800l.available() && _timeout < 12000  )
  {
    delay(13);
    _timeout++;
  }
  if (sim800l.available()) {
    return sim800l.readString();
  }
}

void ReceiveMode() {
  sim800l.println("AT");
  delay(100);
  sim800l.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(100);
  sim800l.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  delay(100);
}

void SendMessage()
{
  //Serial.println ("Sending Message");
  sim800l.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);
  //Serial.println ("Set SMS Number");
  sim800l.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r"); //Mobile phone number to send message
  delay(1000);
  String SMS = "Hello from 800L...";
  sim800l.println(DataSms);
  delay(100);
  sim800l.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
  _buffer = _readSerial();
}
```

Just for your information I'm using Li-Po battery 7.4V 2200mAh

Comment: I suspect that you have power supply issues when you are not connected to the USB.  Using your voltmeter, please measure the Uno's supply voltage when not connected to USB.  Also check the supply voltage for the SIM800 when disconnected.

Comment: You never call `gps.encode(...)` - and anyway, where *is* your GPS connected? I see no SoftwareSerial for it (which by the way can only listen on ONE interface at a time).

Comment: It sounds like but I am only guessing you have a grounding problem. Be sure all the grounds are connected together.  I assume you are connecting the lipo battery to Vin and not the 5V pin. The battery voltage swings to much for stable operation. Be sure to follow jwh20's suggestions and you should be operational.

Comment: @Majenko I'm using digital pin 0 and 1 for my GPS.. that's work fine although I have to disconnected GPS VCC pin first during uploading my program

Comment: @Gil I'm connecting the Li-Po battery to my 5v stepdown then I'm connecting the output of this stepdown to 5v Arduino pin, is this okay to directly connecting 7.4V Li-Po battery to 5v Arduino pin?

Comment: Here I attach my simple schematic wiring of how do I power up my Arduino and another part: https://github.com/Proxcentaur/track-gps-sim/blob/main/wiring.PNG

Comment: @Majenko I have tried using 2 software serial in Arduino Uno but it doesn't work. Then I have decided to use digital pin 0 and 1

Comment: @jwh20 I have measured it, Uno supply voltage when not connected to USB and just connected to battery is 8.04V

Comment: Pins 0 and 1 conflict with the usb serial. You can't j use both.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by click on Arduino reset button pin after all of my components got a power supply. Somehow I can't explain why does it work after doing that simple thing

Comment: Good to hear! It always helps to feed them good electrons:-)